# Refresh expired acess token basics

Tags: support, api, authentication, android, oauth2

I'm trying to learn how to implement an OAuth flow in an Android app using a simple app with the Stack Exchange API.

Using `WebView`, I'm able to retrieve an access token and store it in my shared preferences. My doubt is how to deal with token expiration.

I don't think I'm supposed to show the `WebView` again, am I?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dealing with token expiration is pretty simple.
When a token is/goes bad then, when you make an API call that uses the token, you will get a JSON response like this:

```
{
    "error_id": 403,
    "error_message": "`key` is not valid for passed `access_token`, token not found.",
    "error_name": "access_denied"
}
```

At that point, just re-authenticate.

---

You can also pre-check a token using [the `/access-tokens/{accessTokens}` route](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/read-access-tokens) but that's overkill in must scenarios.

---

I don't recommend using a `no_expiry` token, for security reasons, and even such tokens can be invalidated. So, your app needs to know how to handle bad tokens anyway.

Comment: Ok I understood what you suggest. Nevertheless I still have a big question. Not knowing any other way, I get the token by showing a webView in a Fragment that handles the calls as a browser. When you say re-authenticate do you imply to show that view again? I dont think thats the way other apps are doing it. What am I missing?

Comment: Yes, pretty sure you show that webview again.  At this point, the API doesn't know or care that you'd previously authenticated.  I may be wrong as I'm not an Android developer, but the code I do know just recalls the same routine as for the original login.  Try it and see what happens.